# Is there any way to be notified when callback of asyncFetch is called?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

My code looks like:

```
NetUtil.asyncFetch(url, function(inputStream, status) {
    var binaryOutputStream = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/binaryoutputstream;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces['nsIBinaryOutputStream']);
    var storageStream = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/storagestream;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces['nsIStorageStream']);
    var count = inputStream.available();
    var data = NetUtil.readInputStreamToString(inputStream, count);

    storageStream.init(512, count, null);
    binaryOutputStream.setOutputStream(storageStream.getOutputStream(0));
    binaryOutputStream.writeBytes(data, count);

    global_storageStream = storageStream;
    global_count = count;
})
```

The logic requires the main process to keep being blocked until global_storageStream and global_counter are set.

How can I do?

Comment: The function is asynchronous.  It does not and will not block.  You will need to restructure your code in the main process to deal with that.  You should probably pass in a callback that you can call when everything is done and pass the final two variables to that callback and then put your other code that needs the result in the callback.  That's how you write async code in node.js.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to block the main process at all. Instead call the functionality from the end of your callback.

You could make `global_storageStream` null and keep checking for that, but it's a Bad Idea. You would be doing it wrong if that is your solution.

Here I show a couple of steps to make your code gradually better and more reusable. Arguably it's better and easier to jump to step 2 right away.

**Step 1: Call logic after globals are set**

You should somehow add the follow-up logic to the end of your callback function. So the first step is just putting it there. Of course you don't need the globals then anymore.

```
NetUtil.asyncFetch(url, function(inputStream, status) {
    // Current code clipped for brevity

    // Don't need the globals anymore
    // global_storageStream = storageStream;
    // global_count = count;

    // Code that uses the global storageStream and count can be refactored 
    // to use just the local storageStream and count. 
    yourRefactoredMainProcessLogic.... // Put your logic here.
})
```

**Step 2: Call a separate function and pass arguments**
Or you could wrap the logic in another function that you call afterwards.

```
function afterMath (storageStream, count) {
  // Refactored code of previous step goes here.
  yourRefactoredMainProcessLogic....
}

NetUtil.asyncFetch(url, function(inputStream, status) {
    // Current code clipped for brevity

    afterMath(storageStream, count);
})
```

**Step 3: Wrap in a function with a callback**

Maybe you can wrap it in such a way so you can easily call it, and pass your own callback to be called afterwards. This way, you have an easy, reusable function.

```
function asyncFetchToStream(url, callback) {

    NetUtil.asyncFetch(url, function(inputStream, status) {
        // Current code clipped for brevity
        // Globals still removed, of course.

        // Instead of fixed function, call the callback.
        callback(storageStream, count);
    })
}
```

And then you can call this function like so:

```
asyncFetchToStream('YourUrl', function(storageStream, count){
  // Refactored code of step 1 goes here.
  yourRefactoredMainProcessLogic....
});
```

or, by still calling the named function `afterMath` from the previous step:

```
asyncFetchToStream('YourUrl', afterMath);
```